# how to jquery selection on ids using like a * to match

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of ids for radio buttons on my page:

id="scores_0"
id="scores_1" etc etc..
I am new to jquery and wonder if there is a way to like select anything that sort of matches that.

```
$("#scores_*").css("border", "2px none black")
```

etc ?
or do i have to dynamically regex it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below

```
$('input[id^=scores_]'); //^= StartsWith
$('input[id*=scores_]'); //*= Contains
```

Answer (score 2):

Read here about jQuery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('[id^=scores_]') // <-- this selects all id starting with scores_
```

Comment: @Codejoy glad to help :)  Learning the all the selectors is very useful